# angular js model doesn't bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS and I don't manage to bind properly models that need time to load. I have this service called ListService:

```
angular.module('3pix').factory('ListService', ['$q', '$timeout', 'underscore', 'Item', 'ItemResource',
    function ($q, $timeout, _, Item, ItemResource) {
        var List = function () {
        };
        _.extend(List.prototype, {
            _addItem: function(item) {
                this.items || (this.items = []);
                this.items.push(item);
            },
            loadItems: function() {
                var scope = this;
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                ItemResource.get_items({id: 39}, function(itemsData) {
                    itemsData.forEach(function(itemData) {
                        scope._addItem(new Item(itemData));
                    });
                    deferred.resolve(scope.items);
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        });

        return List;
    }]);
```

My real ListService is far more complicated than this but I copied only the relevant parts so I can ask my question clearly.
My controller called ListController and it gets a 'list' from the router using 'resolve' option:

```
angular.module('3pix').controller('ListController', ['$scope', 'jquery', 'list',
    function ($scope, $, list) {
        $scope.list = list; //<-------- Here I got the list, I get it fine from the router
        list.loadItems(); //<------- Here I load the list's items
}]);
```

In my view I have:

```
<div class="item-wrapper"
     ng-repeat="item in list.items">
     {{item}}
</div>
```

My problem is that after the items are loaded in the controller, the view doesn't displays the items and keeps drawing nothing. I tried to wrap the loadItems's success method in $timeout and $rootScope.$apply but it doesn't help. Any idea how to solve it?

**UPDATE**
I followed the advice of @Chandermani and I did in my controller:

```
list.loadItems().then(function() {
    $scope.items = list.items;
});
```

The items are loaded in the view, but still, sometimes, when I update list.items using _addItem() method, nothing happen and the view doesn't show the new items. I tried to wrap _addItem() with $timeout as follows but it didn't helped either:

```
  _addItem: function(item) {
        $timeout(function() {
            this.items || (this.items = []);
            this.items.push(item);
        });
    }
```

Comment: since you are returning promise where is your then statement in controller ??

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal: What should be the statement in the controller? List.items is changes, shouldn't it effect on the controller's list.item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are assigning the scope list to the service instance instead of the method result.

Change it to

```
angular.module('3pix').controller('ListController', ['$scope', 'jquery', 'list',
    function ($scope, $, list) {
        $scope.list = list.loadItems()
}]);
```

Also can you try this in html

```
ng-repeat="item in list"
```

Comment: list also contains other properties that I need in my views. In my question I reduced the class to what necessary.

Comment: You can still use the list service variable. The `list` service you have defined does not contain any items property that you are binding to. So you either bind the promise or you bind the return value retrieved using `then` method on promise.

Comment: I prefer not to add a property on the controller because I already have this property in the List service. More then that, List has other methods that add items. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I am not talking about adding any property on controller but the sevice you have injected does not have a property `items` which you are trying to bind in the view

Comment: The service does have the property items: List.items holds the items.

Comment: I followed your advice but still I got issues. I updated the question. What do you think?

Comment: Does add item add items to the same array which was binded earlier, put some breakpoint and verify.